# Change outgoing mail address from root@servername - rackspace sendgrid postfix

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, sendgrid, rackspace

So I recently setup my Rackspace server (Ubuntu LAMP stack) to use Postfix and Sendgrid for outgoing email. It works great in that my test mail from the cmd line gets delivered via sendgrid smtp. However, when I receive the email it says its from `root@rackspaceservername` and I cannot reply to it.

I created an alias as per this topic [how to change default email address for postfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538817/how-to-change-default-email-address-for-postfix) which makes it say `webmaster@mydomain.com` by the sender name which still appears as `root`.

What do I need to change to have the server use my webmaster email or at least make it appear thats where it is coming from and thus a reply would go to that email?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mind sharing your config files and what exactly you did to get setup so I can help debug?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make sure this is set in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

When setting a generic alias, don't use "http" like the link you provided - you would use www-data with Ubuntu.

```
echo 'www-data yourusername@yourdomain.com' >> /etc/postfix/generic
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
service postfix restart
```

A side note: Sendgrid is awesome but since Rackspace bought MailGun the MailGun service is pretty much free for Rackspace customers. Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, but how can I change email again? I tried everything, postmap, restart postfix, apache, ... but still same. Some cache?